# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] with multiple OR

Tags: php, request-uri

this work :

```
    <?php
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== '/fr/page1/'){
    echo '<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">';
  }
  ?>
```

(the meta tag not displayed on page 1)

but this not work :

```
    <?php
  if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== '/fr/page1/') || ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== '/fr/page2')){
    echo '<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">';
  }
  ?>
```

the meta tag is displayed on both page :(

Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen when? (We need to know this in order to judge wether your OR logic is correct or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`||` – logical `OR` means if one of the expressions in `some_expr1 || some_expr2 || some_expr3` is evaluated to `TRUE` then the whole expression is evaluated to `TRUE`. I guess you need to change it to logical `AND` – `&&`.